# Insert a Geo Chart in Google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, charts, google-apps-script, google-sheets

From what i saw, these are the supported embedded charts : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/chart-type
Inserting one of these chart type is easy but my goal is to insert a geo chart in spreadsheet. It is possible manually, but i don't know how to do this programaticly. I red that Geo charts are supported in Google Charts : https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart
Maybe i should use google visualization api?

Comment: Unfortunately, GeoChart is not in the list of ChartTypes. I haven't tried this but you may like to use [Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/glossary) and accessing it thru [urlFetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) or using [htmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) and posting it in the sidebar since you are inserting an html to the sheets. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you !That is what I thought
 Unfortunatly i can't display the chart in the sidebar (i don't have the choice, it's for an internship)

Comment: @JeanSec Could you put it into a modal instead?

Comment: no, my dashboard must be in a spreadsheet, made out of embedded charts.